# How do you pass an array-like object array to a function like this? (scikit-learn.neighbors.KDTree)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, kdtree

We have this nice KDTree constructor which takes in a numpy array, now I have a use case where I want to pass the name associated with each point in 3D space along with that point, so when I query for the point and get it back, I can also get it's name. This is super userful in debugging.

My question: How do I get this done using this interface which takes in an array-like object.
 http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html

An example to make things more clear:

Say I have a bunch of points like this:

```
[[1, 1, 1.1],
 [1, 1, 1.2], 
 [1, 1, 100]]
```

and each point has a name, a, b and c.

The way to construct a KDTree is just tree = KDTree(X) where X is the matrix above. Now if I query the KDTree with the point [1, 1, 1] I get back the first two points above (say). Now how do I also get back the names of those points as a and b. Currently, the only way I know to do this is to keep the second dictionary with the names. But for a very large set of points, this seems a waste of space and elegance.

Would the original API permit storing a name along with the point? How to do it if it is possible.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: If you don't need to directly use that function, you can write a wrapper that translates back and forth from point name to coordinates.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added an example.

Comment: Not in the current form. All arrays supplied to KDTree will be converted to numpy arrays internally, so that indexing information will be lost. Unless you use a wrapper as @aryamccarthy suggested and for that dictionary based naming is a good solution